# How to pass a text box value in html onclick event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am using a asp.net web application. In that Application I am having one text box in a web page to get inputs from user. Now I need to read the value in HTML source page as I have mentioned below.

```
 <a href="" onclick="editDocumentWithProgID2('textbox1.text', '', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '0', 'http://demo-1/blankpage', '0')">Edit onclick</a>
```

In the above line I am not able to get the textbox1 value. I need to pass the textbox value as dynamically. How can I do this ? What I need to change in this code? Please help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the markup for textbox?

Comment: instead of struggling like this you can use jquery function and possibly can do it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scriptlet to get ClientID if the `ClientIDMode` of TextBox is not `static`. You can use `document.getElementById` to get the DOM object for your TextBox control

```
onclick="editDocumentWithProgID2(document.getElementById('<%= textbox1.ClientID %>').value, '0', 'http://demo-1/blankpage', '0')">Edit onclick</a>
```

Or you can call a function (parameterless) from onclick and call editDocumentWithProgID2 from that function to make the call more readable.

*Html*

```
<a href="" onclick="someFun();" > Edit onclick</a>
```

*Javascript*

```
function someFun()
{
    editDocumentWithProgID2(document.getElementById('<%= textbox1.ClientID %>').value,, '0', 'http://demo-1/blankpage', '0'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try document.getElementById to get the exact element id.

```
 <a href="" onclick="editDocumentWithProgID2(document.getElementById('<%= textbox1.ClientID %>').value >Edit onclick</a>
```